# Python - How to search for HTML in a web browser

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to figure out a way to have python search in inspect element at a certain xpath for a certain number.  So if an image is constantly changing between 3 pictures and keeps a log of the last pictures, how can I make python distinguish between the three and the past 10?
So for example, the html looks something like this:

"13"
' class="ball ball-1">5'

but there are 10 in a row, how can I make python take the most recent one?

Comment: Beautiful soup might help you with this: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
   url = "yourUrl"
   page = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
   resultado = ""

   #look for the sure element
   for link in page.xpath("//image[@class='ball ball-1']"):
      print link.text
```

This way you can get all the images with this class, even its history